# Hadoop Counters documentation?

Tags: hadoop, counter

After my `MapReduce` job finishes, I get a whole lot of `Counter` information:

```
File System Counters
                FILE: Number of bytes read=4386096368
                FILE: Number of bytes written=8805370803
                FILE: Number of read operations=0
                FILE: Number of large read operations=0
                FILE: Number of write operations=0
                HDFS: Number of bytes read=54583718086
                HDFS: Number of bytes written=4382090874
                HDFS: Number of read operations=1479
                HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
                HDFS: Number of write operations=2
        Job Counters
                Launched map tasks=369
                Launched reduce tasks=1
                Data-local map tasks=369
                Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=34288552
                Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=232084
                Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=8572138
                Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=58021
                Total vcore-seconds taken by all map tasks=8572138
                Total vcore-seconds taken by all reduce tasks=58021
                Total megabyte-seconds taken by all map tasks=35111477248
                Total megabyte-seconds taken by all reduce tasks=237654016
        Map-Reduce Framework
                Map input records=14753874
                Map output records=666776
                Map output bytes=4383426830
                Map output materialized bytes=4386098552
                Input split bytes=47970
                Combine input records=0
                Combine output records=0
                Reduce input groups=1
                Reduce shuffle bytes=4386098552
                Reduce input records=666776
                Reduce output records=666776
                Spilled Records=1333552
                Shuffled Maps =369
                Failed Shuffles=0
                Merged Map outputs=369
                GC time elapsed (ms)=1121584
                CPU time spent (ms)=23707900
                Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=152915259392
                Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=2370755190784
                Total committed heap usage (bytes)=126644912128
        Shuffle Errors
                BAD_ID=0
                CONNECTION=0
                IO_ERROR=0
                WRONG_LENGTH=0
                WRONG_MAP=0
                WRONG_REDUCE=0
        File Input Format Counters
                Bytes Read=49449743227
        File Output Format Counters
                Bytes Written=4382090874
```

Where can I find an explanation for what each of these fields mean? Some of them are fairly obvious  (`Number of bytes read`), but others are more ambiguous (`Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots` vs `Total time spent by all map tasks`).

I found a [list of all the default counters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13609028/is-there-a-list-of-all-standard-not-custom-hadoop-mapreduce-counters), but I can't seem to find an explanation or description of them.

I'm fairly surprised that I can't seem to easily find documentation about this output. Can anyone provide a link or an explanation?

Comment: See this link for some info on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25482426/explanation-for-hadoop-mapreduce-console-output

Comment: The explanation for these counters are available in Chapter 8 (Map Reduce Features) of the Book
Hadoop - The Definitive Guide 3rd Edition by Tom White Hope this helps.
Raj

Answer (score 0):

Chapter 8 of the [Hadoop: The Definitive Guide](http://eecs.wsu.edu/~yinghui/mat/courses/fall%202015/resources/Hadoop%20the%20definitive%20guide.pdf) (full PDF in link from Washington State University), provides details of Counters, to do with `MapReduce`. This starts on page 225 and are listed in Table 8-1. A more up to date edition (4th) of this resource is available at [Safari Books Online](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/hadoop-the-definitive/9781491901687/ch09.html) (you will need to log in first).